# How to compute hash on Oracle XMLType?

Tags: xml, oracle

I'd like to compute a lot of hash values on XML stored as binary XMLType. It should be fairly safe for collisions (we have a couple of million records), but doesn't need to be cryptographically strong.

I'd tried `ORA_HASH`, which apparently doesn't like XML. And I applied for access to `DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH`. Is it necessary to cast it to RAW?

Comment: No, but you'd need to extract the Clob value; I think [this is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23237770/266304), would you agree?

Comment: @AlexPoole: but of course it is, thanks for finding it. How do I close the question?

Comment: It's easier to find questions I remember answering before *8-) I wasn't 100% sure it actually addressed your issue, but I have closed this a duplicate now. Thanks.