# ROWNUM works only for one row. How to fetch rows after that?

Tags: oracle, plsql, blob, rownum

I want to extract BLOB data and write a file (suggest it should be excel or txt or any other) out of it. A single cell has upto 60k characters. I wanted to write a script that reads whole table with BLOB data and write into a file. In below code ROWNUM works only for one row. what's the alternative? Or is there another script that can help me to achieve my ultimate objective to read BLOB and write file?

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
    DECLARE
       TotalRows NUMBER;
       TotalChar NUMBER;
       CharCounter NUMBER;
    BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) INTO TotalRows FROM <TableName>;
            --dbms_output.Put_line(RC);
            --END;
       FOR RC IN 1..TotalRows
       LOOP
           -----------------Code for Rows starts--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            dbms_output.Put_line('Row '||RC||' Started.');
            SELECT Length(<ColumnWithBLOBDataType>) INTO TotalChar FROM <TableName> where **Rownum = RC**;
            dbms_output.Put_line('Crossed Char counting query. TotalChar='||TotalChar);
            CharCounter:=TotalChar/2000+1;
            dbms_output.Put_line('Loop will run these many times= '||CharCounter|| ' and Total Chars=' ||TotalChar);
            For CC IN 1..CharCounter
            LOOP
                dbms_output.Put_line('Trip: '||CC);
            END LOOP;  
        -----------------Code for Rows Ends----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            TotalChar :=0;
            dbms_output.Put_line('Row '|| RC||' Done. TotalChar='|| TotalChar);
       END LOOP;
       dbms_output.Put_line('Exited loop 1.');
    END;
```

Comment: "writes it into a file": do you want to write all blobs into one, single, big file?

Comment: BLOB data is basically application configuration data which I want to read and want to compare with same configuration after changes to pin point all the changes made. Plz suggest if there is a better way to achieve that. I was thinking to write that in a file and compare with another file generated after changes. Thanks!

Comment: The max chars in a cell i saw was 60k chars. And configuration file that is created by the application is of less than 50MB. Please suggest feasible/best solution considering I am not an expert in programming howeever can do a little bit coding in PL SQL, VB, .net etc.

Comment: If it's configuration data, then `CLOB` might be a better datatype than `BLOB` which is for binary data.

Comment: Personally, I'd probably leave the data in the database and make a snapshot of the before state: `CREATE TABLE mybefore AS SELECT * FROM mytable`. After the change, I'd compare the table mybefore and mytable to let SQL find which cells have changed...

Comment: Thanks Mate! However I think we will be able to find where it changed but not what changed. Table has 4 columns and only 23 rows. BLOB column has 22k to characters 60k hexadecimal characters and I assume lot of objects are contained within one cell. Problem is we are not aware of data and its structure. Is there a way to compare two tables?

Comment: Yes, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676737/compare-blob-against-other-blobs-in-oracle-database). Ideally, you would have some sort of `diff` comparison, but I don't know of one.

Answer (score 1):

You normally don't use `ROWNUM` to select rows from a table. It's not safe and not necessary. Normally, you can do it with a single `FOR SELECT` loop:

```
DECLARE
   CharCounter NUMBER;
   part VARCHAR2(30000);
   offset NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT c,
                   rownum as rc,
                   dbms_lob.getlength(c) as totalchar
              FROM mytable)
  LOOP
    -----------------Code for Rows starts--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    dbms_output.put_line('Row '||r.rc||' Started.');

    dbms_output.put_line('Crossed Char counting query. TotalChar='||r.totalchar);

    offset := 1;
    WHILE (offset <= r.totalchar) LOOP
      part := dbms_lob.substr(r.c, 20000, offset);
      offset := offset + length(part);      
      dbms_output.put(part);
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line('');

  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and will let you know.

Comment: Mate I tried this, it works, ie it goes through all the rows however due to Character String Buffer, it gives error (ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small).

Comment: Mate I tried this, it works, i.e. it goes through all the rows however due to Character String Buffer, it gives error (ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small. ORA-06512: at line 13
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"). If i decrease 20000 to 15000 in (part := dbms_lob.substr(r.DATA, 20000, offset), it returns 11 rows along with this same error. Also, I tried to use utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 with dbms_lob.substr(r.DATA, 20000, offset) at r.DATA, then it has same error as above with zero rows.

Comment: This might be a multibyte character problem. The max length of a PL/SQL VARCHAR2 is 32767. A character can have max 4 bytes. Therefore I'd try with a buffer size of 8000.

Comment: And, this answer shows only how to read the data from your table. It's not a good method to write to one or more files...

Comment: Thanks, Any way to create the file please?

Comment: That's a separate question ;-) It can be done with `UTL_FILE`, but the file needs to be reachable from the database server.

Comment: Your welcome. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers